# Not receiving new listings from CREA DDF

Tags: rets, phrets, mls, ddf

We are now working on a new project integrating one of our client's website with CREA DDF.

We are now fetching and updating/creating listings based on the list of updated listings from DDF API. However, at some point, we stopped getting any new listings.

A question that I could not clearly get an answer for in the documentation:
[image]
Does `Retrieve all active records updated since a specified date/time` call include new listings as well?

Comment: AFAIK new listings are considered active listings.

Comment: @slim Yeah, that was our assumption as well. But it seems like it does not work.

Comment: Which date field are you querying exactly? The status change timestamp? A new listing wouldn't have a value for that field yet and therefore wouldn't show up in your search. Just a thought.

Comment: @slim well, I am following the docs. So, it the LastUpdated

Comment: Can you try this: Query the MLS for new listings and check the value of the LastUpdated field to see if it's set to anything. Also, can you include the actual DMQL query you're running in your question?

Comment: New listings will be retrieved using LastUpdated